# Why is 2 meter pre-programed?

Tags: 2m-band

When I tried to enter frequencies in my 2 meter YAESU, it was already programmed for 144.000 MHz as the primary. WHY?

Comment: Is there some other behavior you are expecting?

Comment: "primary" what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to be more specific about what “the primary” is (give your radio model and the exact words/labels it uses in your question) for a more definite answer, but most likely it's simply that 144.000 MHz is the lowest frequency that is part of the 2-meter band ([this is true worldwide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-meter_band)), so it's a reasonable place to start for a VFO which has got to have *some* frequency to be on.

Note that you should not actually transmit on 144.000 MHz, because it *is* the lower band edge, and so the lower sideband of your signal would extend outside of the band.

Answer (score 2):

It's just the default setting. You can change it either through the menus or with the software, depending on which model radio you have.